# Expected value of Ito integral

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expectation, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I am trying to understand why $$E\bigg[\exp\big(a^\frac{1}{2}\int f(t)dW(t)\big)\bigg]=\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}a\int f(t)^2dt\right),$$ 
but I'm having trouble with Ito integration in general. I was able to show that if $Z(t)=\exp(a\cdot W(t))$, then $E[Z(t)]=\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}a^2t\right),$ but in my current problem, I have the integral $\int f(t)dW(t)$ rather than just $W(t)$, so I'm starting to doubt whether this is the right approach.

Comment: Assuming $a\neq 0$, $Z'(t)=aW'(t)e^{aW(t)}$ so $dW=(e^{-aW}/a)dZ$.

Comment: @anderstood Hmm, what? Sorry but these are stochastic integrals, hence the computation in your comment is plain false.

Comment: @Did For my knowledge, what is wrong: the differentation?

Comment: @anderstood Check `Ito's formula`.

Comment: @Did So $f(t)$ implicitly depends on another variable, which is a random variable; is that correct?

Comment: @anderstood Completely unrelated.

Comment: @Did I'm trying to understand why, if $Z$ is a function of a real variable $t$ such that $Z(t)=e^{aW(t)}$, it is wrong to say $Z'(t)=aW'(t)e^{aW(t)}$. I've been through [Itô's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma)'s page, but I don't quite see the contradiction. Could you enlighten me?

Comment: @anderstood First and foremost, because $t\mapsto W(t)$ is almost surely not differentiable. Second, because if you had looked at the statement of Itô's lemma, you might have noticed that $Z_t=g(W_t)$ with $g$ of class $C^2$ (here, $g(x)=e^{ax}$) implies $dZ_t=g'(W_t)dW_t+\frac12g''(W_t)dt$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

1. The random variable $X := \int f(t) \, dW_t$ is a Gaussian random variable. Determine by its mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
2. Recall that for any Gaussian random variable $X$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ it holds that $$\mathbb{E}(e^{\lambda X} )= \exp \left(-\lambda \mu+ \frac{1}{2} \lambda^2 \sigma^2 \right)$$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.
3. Conclude.

**Remark:** I take it that $f$ is deterministic, i.e. $f=f(t)$ does not depend on $\omega$. Otherwise the claim does obviously hold not true since the right-hand side is a (non-trivial) random variable and the left-hand side a constant.

Comment: I see it! Since $\int f(t)dW_t\sim N(0,\int f(t)^2dt)$, we get the answer from step 2.

Comment: @AlbertFletcher Yes, exactly.